# Unable to properly set tint on child of LayerDrawable on Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

**TLDR;** I am tinting the icons of my Menu's MenuItems by wrapping them in another Drawable and tinting that, and this works. Except for the case where my original Drawable is inside of a LayerDrawable. Then it does not work. It is as if my code has no effect whatsoever whatever I try to do. Code is below, along with screenshots, for details, read the rest.

**UPDATE:** If I remove the `android:visible="false"` in the XML, it works. The same happens though if I in the code do `menuItem.isVisible = false` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`. When it becomes visible again, it is visually stuck in this black color with some sort of transparency blended into it. I do however not want to show this button unless it is relevant, so making it invisible is what I want.

The reason I am manually tinting is because I use [Cyanea Theme Engine](https://github.com/jaredrummler/Cyanea) to dynamically theme my app during runtime, and Cyanea deals with this throughout the app's life cycle, but for some reason MenuItems do not get their colors applied, so I have to do this manually, which I have successfully done. But I can't seem to have an icon with a badge that can be tinted, no matter the kind of solution I choose to go for, which currently is [this one at medium.com](https://medium.com/mindorks/making-actionbar-beautiful-by-showing-count-on-actionbar-icon-ed3a3a1a74ea).

I am trying to stick to Drawable APIs so that I don't need to do something more custom, but I am stuck. Defining the Drawable in XML does not work, and creating it programatically does not work. It runs and has the correct icon and correct badge count, but not the correct color, in both cases.

I thought it might have to do with `icon.mutate()` not being called properly. I also thought that maybe setting the badge count causes it, overriding the new tint with the original one, but it does not seem to affect the icon at all one way or another. At the bottom are three screenshots where I have tested three different cases with two icons. Note the slight difference in color between the left and the right one when both are the default color black.

Related issue that required this manual tinting to begin with:

Through previous googling I found a solution to a problem where [Cyanea Theme Engine](https://github.com/jaredrummler/Cyanea) does not apply its theme to MenuItem icons, meaning their drawables do not get the proper color. The solution I found was similar to this but it was written in Java, and I've tweaked mine over time, especially when trying to solve this current problem.

**NOTE:** I am open to suggestions on solving the original problem of creating a `MenuItem` icon that can have a dynamic notification count in a badge, if it works with this dynamic tinting of the icon itself at the same time, **BUT** I still want to learn why this does not work as it stands now.

```
object MenuItemExtensions {
    fun tintMenuIcon(item: MenuItem, color: Int) {
        when (val drawable = item.icon.mutate()) {
            is LayerDrawable -> {
                val id = R.id.badge_bottom_layer
                val normal = drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(id)
                val wrapped = wrapIcon(normal, color)
                drawable.setDrawableByLayerId(id, wrapped)
                item.icon = drawable
            }
            else -> {
                item.icon = wrapIcon(normalDrawable = drawable, color = color)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun wrapIcon(normalDrawable: Drawable, color: Int): Drawable {
        val wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color)
        return wrapDrawable
    }
}
```

I call this function like this:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.friend_list_menu, menu)
    menu.findItem(R.id.friend_list_add_friend_button)?.let {
        // This works
        applyMenuItemColor(menuItem = it)
        it.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            val directions = FriendListFragmentDirections.navGraphActionFriendsToAddFriend()
            findNavController().navigate(directions)
            true
        }
        addFriendButton = it
    }
    menu.findItem(R.id.friend_list_requests_button)?.let {
        // This is the original version, the one that works for normal Drawables
        applyMenuItemColor(menuItem = it)
        // This is an attempt at creating the same structure but entirely programmatically.
        buildBadgeIcon(menuItem = it)
        // Both yield the same results, which fails for LayerDrawable, 
        // and they're not both called at the same time
        it.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            Timber.d { "Clicked friend requests button" }
            true
        }
        friendRequestsButton = it
    }
}

private fun applyMenuItemColor(menuItem: MenuItem) {
    // This color works as properly, as the icon next to it has been colored properly,
    // which is WHITE in the current settings theme. Changing this to Color.RED changes nothing,
    // the icon remains black (incorrect).
    MenuItemExtensions.tintMenuIcon(menuItem, Cyanea.instance.menuIconColor)
}

private fun buildBadgeIcon(menuItem: MenuItem) {
    val context = requireContext()
    val bottomIcon: Drawable = requireNotNull(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)?.let {
            DrawableCompat.wrap(DrawableCompat.wrap(it)).apply {
                setTint(Cyanea.instance.menuIconColor)
            }
        }
    )
    val topIcon: Drawable = requireNotNull(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.color.transparent))
    val layerDrawable = LayerDrawable(arrayOf(bottomIcon, topIcon))
    menuItem.icon = layerDrawable
}
```

The icon is a default imported icon through Android Studio. The layer list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/badge_bottom_layer"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/badge_top_layer"
        android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

</layer-list>
```

**Menu XML:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/friend_list_add_friend_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/add_friend"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/friend_list_requests_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/badge_background"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/friend_requests"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

**Neither icon colored with Cyanea:**

[image: Neither icon colored with Cyanea]

**Both icons colored with Cyanea:**

[image]

**Both icons colored with Cyanea and BadgeCount layer is turned on:**

[image]